# Installing cPickle fails

Tags: python-2.7, pickle

I am working on ubuntu 14.04. Python version: 2.7.6. 
I am trying to install cPickle, but I am getting error: 
"could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement cPickle"
I tried via, pip and apt-get as well. What might be reason, has this package been removed completely?

Comment: `cPickle` is installed when `python` itself is installed -- it's part of the standard library.  So, just `import cPickle` and it should be there.

Comment: You _could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement cPickle_, because there is no package named cPickle in pypi. You can browse all packages [on official pypi web page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=index).

Comment: Thanks MIke and Rogalski, I got the clarification. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I tried importing cPickle and it worked. But I don't know why the error "could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement cPickle". I will appreciate if someone can provide reason.

Also as commented by mike cleared my doubt. 
"cPickle is installed when python itself is installed -- it's part of the standard library. So, just import cPickle and it should be there"